# Alter Table gives error #1064

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create two tables in phpmyadmin: Users and Keys, the schema is as follows:

**Users**:

```
id int auto_incerement primary key

name varchar(50) not null
```

**Keys**:

```
user_id int

keys varchar(50) not null
```

Now I am running the following query to make the `user_id` in `Keys` a foreign key referencing the `id` in `Users`

```
ALTER TABLE Keys
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES Users(id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But after executing, i am getting the following error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Keys FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES Users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CA' at line 1`

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just throwing it out there...you say you're using phpMyAdmin, but you're working with SQL statements. Everything you're doing above can be done graphically from phpMyAdmin (which does properly escape table names and reserved words and so on. There's nothing wrong with typing the SQL statement, but it's also easy to do these things graphically. phpMyAdmin has several tools to work with relations (Relation View, Designer, etc).

Comment: i know it is easy to use the GUI, but where's the fun in that? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Keys` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and must be encased in backticks:

```
ALTER TABLE `Keys`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES `Users` (`id`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

It's best practice to encase all system related words in backticks.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I changed the query to what you have written, it is still giving me the error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY(\`user_id\`) REFERENCES Users(\`id\`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASC' at line 2`

Comment: Try dropping the backticks around the foreign key name.

Comment: doesn't work still :/

Comment: Are you receiving the same error?

Comment: this is the error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES \`Users\`(\`id\`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASC' at line 2`

Comment: We're missing the `ADD` before `FOREIGN KEY`....

Comment: the query didn't give an error, but neither did it show any confirmation, is there any way i could check if it succeeded?

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE *Keys*` (replace `*` with a backtick)

Answer (score 2):

`KEYS` is a reserved keyword. See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

You need to wrap them in backticks:

```
ALTER TABLE `Keys`
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose keys with [back tick.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)

```
ALTER TABLE `Keys`
```